# How to check if a `std::vector<bool>` is true at multiple indexes simultaneously?

Tags: c++, vector, boolean

I have a `std::vector<bool>` of size N and a `std::vector<std::size_t>` of variable size containing indexes in `[0, N)`. What is an idiomatic way to check if the first vector is true at all indexes given by the second vector?

My possibly naive solution is:

```cpp
auto all_true(
    std::vector<bool> const& bools, std::vector<std::size_t> const& indexes)
    -> bool {
  auto res = true;
  for (auto index : indexes) {
    res = res and bools[index];
  }
  return res;
}
```

Comment: Not a wholly different solution, but a more efficient way to do your solution would be to return false if !bools[index] then return true on loop exit, rather than storing res.

Comment: I think the most idiomatic way to do this would be to create an iterator adaptor which is constructed from iterators over the data and indices and iterates over the relevant data values then call std::all_of on that.

Comment: I think the best way is to do it as clearly as possible. Your implementation seems fine (though you can exit early on finding a non true value). An alternative would be to use `std::find_if()`.

Comment: Side note: Now that I’m looking at this again, my `std::accumulate` idea below (and in fact also the code in the question) may be hugely inefficient when (e.g.) the size of `bools` is *O(quadratic)* whereas the first `false` is expected to occur somewhere within the *O(linear)* first members. (Plug in an arbitrary other complexity-changing statistic.) So ideally the `all_true` should do `for (auto index : indexes) if (!bools[index]) return false; return true;` to short-circuit the evaluation. (This would be different if `bools[index]` had an important side effect, but in this case it doesn’t.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An *idiomatic* (though not necessarily *efficient*) way to do this would be to use the [`std::all_of` STL function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/all_any_none_of), using a predicate that simply returns the value of the Boolean vector at the index specified by each value in the `size_t` vector.

Here's an outline/demo:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>

bool all_true(const std::vector<bool>& data, const std::vector<size_t>& test)
{
    return std::all_of(test.begin(), test.end(), [&data](size_t n) { return data[n]; });
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<bool> bools{ true, true, true, true, false, false, true, false, true, false };
    std::vector<size_t> test1{  0,    1,    2,    3,                  6,           8        }; // all true
    std::vector<size_t> test2{  0,    1,    2,           4,                  7,           9 }; // some false

    std::cout << "Test1: " << all_true(bools, test1) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Test2: " << all_true(bools, test2) << "\n\n";

    // Just to show that the order doesn't matter ...
    std::cout << "After shuffling ...\n";
    std::random_device rdev;
    std::mt19937 rgen(rdev());
    std::shuffle(test1.begin(), test1.end(), rgen);
    std::shuffle(test2.begin(), test2.end(), rgen);
    std::cout << "Test1: " << all_true(bools, test1) << "\n";
    std::cout << "Test2: " << all_true(bools, test2) << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't think using functors is idiomatic anymore now that we have lambda.

Comment: @MartinYork I don't disagree. The functor approach came more naturally (to me) ... but I'll see if I can work up a lambda equivalent.

Comment: You should capture `[&data]` (a reference) instead of `[data]` (a copy).

Comment: @Andrej Yes, indeed ... edited.

Comment: Why could this not be efficient when the standard states the complexity is "At most last - first applications of the predicate"?

Answer (score 2):

Don't think your code is not idiomatic.
The range based `for()` is there to handle this type of situation. Especially if you are writing a named function to encapsulate it.

```
auto allTrue(std::vector<bool> const& data, std::vector<std::size_t> const& indexs) -> bool
{
    for (auto index: indexs) {
        if (!data[index]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Pre range based iterator I would say use a standard function that uses iterators.

```
auto allTrue(std::vector<bool> const& data, std::vector<std::size_t> const& indexs) -> bool
{
    return std::all_of(std::begin(indexs), std::end(indexs),
                [&data](std::size_t i){return data[i];}
           );
}
```

Maybe: If you are not going to wrap it in a function then using this `std::all_of()` function directly in place in the code it makes it more intuitive to read, then use it. But if you are writing the function anyway use the range based for.

Or if you have C++20

```
auto allTrue(std::vector<bool> const& data, std::vector<std::size_t> const& indexs) -> bool
{
    return std::ranges::all_of(indexs, [&data](std::size_t i){return data[i];});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another option would be `std::accumulate`. If the result type and the input `std::vector` element type were the same, you could instead use a (more efficient) `std::reduce`. However, in this case you need to (sort of) accumulate `size_t`s (indices pointing into a `std::vector` of `bool`s) into a `bool` result:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  const std::vector<bool> bools{true, true, false, true, true};
  const std::vector<size_t> i1{1, 4, 3, 0};  // true && true && true && true
  const std::vector<size_t> i2{0, 2, 4, 3};  // true && false && true && true

  const auto and_by_idx{
      [&bools](bool acc, size_t idx) { return acc && bools[idx]; }};

  std::cout << std::boolalpha
            << std::accumulate(i1.begin(), i1.end(), true, and_by_idx) << '\n'
            << std::accumulate(i2.begin(), i2.end(), true, and_by_idx) << '\n';
}
```

I wouldn’t call any of the C++ solutions *idiomatic* though. Some other languages have shorter and more elegant ways to express this, like Python and its `all()`.

```py
bools = (True, True, False, True, True)
i1 = (1, 4, 3, 0)  # True && True && True && True
i2 = (0, 2, 4, 3)  # True && False && True && True

print(all(bools[i] for i in i1))
print(all(bools[i] for i in i2))
```